# Regularity of product measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces and $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ are finite regular Borel measure spaces.
(By regular I mean that every measurable set can be approximated from above by open measurable sets and from below by compact measurable sets.)
Let $\mu \times \nu$ be product measure on $(X \times Y, \mathcal A \times \mathcal B)$.
I believe I can show that $\mu \times \nu$ must be regular, but I am looking for a simpler proof.